# Does chef-client use a local cache? If so, can I clear it?

Tags: chef, chef-server

This might be a stupid question. I don't know a lot about chef. I am using chef 11.8.2 on a node. I have a [weird problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/801103/attributes-not-being-updated-in-chef) which might be caused by the chef client caching things rather than downloading from the chef server. *Does* chef do this? Cache things locally? If so, is it possible to clear the local cache on a chef node before running `chef-client` so that I can be sure that my problem isn't from caching?

Answer (score 5):

If you're running on linux, you should be able to find it at `/var/chef/cache`.

It stores the pid file there by default as well.

Answer (score 0):

While you noticed in the other question that this wasn't a cache issue on the node (rather that the Chef Server's view of node data is only a snapshot), Chef does have some cache data on each node. Mostly this is just cookbook file data since we have to download it before execution.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having issues with caches. What I did to make my knife bootstrap work is to delete some cookbooks related to the issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're afflicted with systemd, maybe this will help?

```
cat<<EOF>/etc/tmpfile.d/chef
e   /var/chef/cache - - - 1 - 
EOF
```